# Is it OK to create a class containing constants in Flash?

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

So, I'm trying to have some constants that can be accessed by every class in my ActionScript 3 program. I use FlashDevelop, and I created this:

```
package
{
    public class ConstClass
    {
         public static const alpha : int = 30;
         public static const beta : Boolean = true;
    }
}
```

I can use it at my program like this: `sigma = ConstClass.alpha + 10`, for example. Now, my question is this:
1. Will it negatively impact on the performance of my program?
2. Is there a better way to implement the same effect with faster way?

Comment: The convention for this is uppercase, follow adobe example Event.MOUSE_MOVE

Answer (score 0):

You mean static? Const modifier makes your field immutable, but static gives class access.

1. It depends on your program or how you use static fields. For example access to local variables is much more faster. Nevertheless, it's normal practice to use static fields for saving primitive immutable data or utility functions.
2. What do you mean faster? Faster for typing or performance? Again it depends on your code.

[Interesting tests](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1690), but anyway, influence on performance is minimal.